# namespaces including functions with same names in cpp file

Tags: c++, namespaces, overloading

I have a header "myhead" including two namespaces:

```
namespace A {

    void fnc(T arg);
}

namespace B {

    void fnc();
}
```

I also have a cpp file:

```
#include "myHead"

A::fnc(T arg) {...}
B::fnc() {...}
```

It never executes B:fnc(); although I call it with its namespace in main. With execute, I mean `B::fnc()` never gets called. Is this because of function overloading? If so, how it could be possible if the function defined with its namespace? There is no compile error.

main:

```
void main {

    ...
    A::fnc(arg);
    B::fnc();    // this never gets executed
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "It never executes", compiler error? or you are `cout`ing something and it is not being printed on the screen?

Comment: It's impossible, it really **must** get executed unless the program terminates right before it is called, did you try debugging or `cout`ing something?

Comment: sorry I made a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cpp file should look something like this:

```
#include "myHead"

namespace A {
  fnc(T arg) {...}
}

namespace B {
 fnc() {...}
}
```